# How to fix "Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\rodri\nodejs_paypal\src\index.js'" in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs

I'm trying to run my Node.js project, but I'm encountering the following module resolution error:

```
PS C:\Users\rodri\nodejs_paypal> npm run dev 

 nodejs_paypal@1.0.0 dev  babel-node src/index.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936   throw err;   ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\rodri\nodejs_paypal\src\index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) 
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rodri\nodejs_paypal\node_modules\@babel\node\lib\_babel-node.js:176:21)ejs_paypal\node_modules\@babel\node\lib\_babe/cjs/loader:1105:14)l-node.js:176:21) ternal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/loader:981:32)/cjs/loader:1105:14)              odules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:inMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)ternal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10) 47 {
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) 
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] } PS C:\Users\rodri\nodejs_paypal>
```

**Project Structure:**

**index.js**

```
import express from 'express'
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "nodejs_paypal",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "babel-node src/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/node": "^7.18.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.9",
    "babel-install": "2.1.0"
  }
}
```

**My index file is here:**

[image]

**What I've Tried:**

- I've checked the file path in my project and in the error message, and they seem to match. I'm not sure why the module can't be found.

**Question:**

How can I resolve this "Cannot find module" error and ensure my project runs correctly?

Comment: Maybe: `"dev": "babel-node src/routes/index.js"` in package.json? As the command is not able to find the index.js file. Make sure the file pathe here in dev script is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong but your `index.js` file seems to be inside the `routes` folder...

Try to move it "up" into the `src` folder, or update the path in the "dev" script of your `package.json`.

Answer (score 1):

Delete node modules and package-lock.json

> run npm install

Comment: Hello, don't work

Comment: Bro delete node modules and package-lock.json and run npm install